# Wordpress current month users

Tags: users

How to display list of current month user in wordpress?

```
  <?php $blogusers = get_users( array( 'role' => 'game', 'order' => 'DESC', 'number'  => 50) );
    foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {  ?>

  <p class="cardname--text"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></p>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'current month users'? Most recently joined, most posts, most comments, most logins, most page views, something else? Depending on what you want you might need to add some tracking as not all of these are recorded automatically.

Comment: I want to show only Current month registered Users list. For example, Current month is April, so I want to show all the Registered users of current month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `get_users` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) with `date_query` !

```
$month_users = get_users(array(
    'date_query'        => array(
        array(
            'after' => 'first day of this month',
            'before' => 'last day of this month',
            'inclusive' => true
        ),
    ),
));
if(!empty($month_users))
{
    foreach($month_users as $k => $v)
    {
        echo 'User : '.$v->display_name.'<br>';
    }    
}
```

Comment: Not working, still getting all list of users

Comment: Oh strange this code works on my side ! :/

Comment: In my wordpress site, users are registered from Feburary, I saw only Feburary month users are hidden by using this code but March month registered users are still showing. 

I want to show only current month users. Like current month is April, so I want to show only April month users.

Comment: Oh ok, si instead of '-1 month' we must set it to the first day of the current month ! I'll update after breakfast ! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort :)

Comment: Can you try with "first day of this month" ? :)

Comment: Now, it's showing only April 1st users, I want to show all users of April(current) month.

Comment: It is showing only 1st April users

Comment: Thank you :) It works fine

Comment: You're welcome :)